# Site needs massive upgrade - how to proceed?

Tags: upgrade

I have a former customer who, contrary to my recommendations, has not stayed on top of their WP upgrades. They now need to make the leap from 3.5.1 to 4.1.1 (or whatever is current at the moment). They used a fairly vanilla theme (might have even been Twenty Eleven), and not used too many plugins.

I have found numerous threads (here and elsewhere) that talk about doing this 1 mini-upgrade at a time. Is this really necessary, or can bigger steps be taken? E.g. 3.5.1 -> 3.9, then 3.9 -> 4.0, and then 4.0 -> 4.1.1

Thoughts or experiences are appreciated.

Comment: step 1- back up the files and database and mirror it in a test installation. then you can test whatever upgrade process you choose with no risk.

Comment: OK. I have an ancient copy of BackupBuddy that seems to work in this environment, so I'll use that. Thanks!

Comment: Make sure to turn debug on, some functions was depreciated between 3.5 and 4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the Codex on [Upgrading Across Multiple versions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Upgrading_WordPress_Extended#Upgrading_Across_Multiple_Versions).

Regarding the upgrading steps, it says:

> If you plan on upgrading across more than two major releases, please
>   consider upgrading incrementally to avoid potential conflicts and
>   minimize the risks of database damage. For example, if you plan on
>   upgrading from 2.5 to 4.1.1, upgrade to 2.7 first, followed by 2.9,
>   then 3.1, and so on. Essentially, it's okay to skip one release, but
>   never skip TWO when upgrading.

So according to this advice, your upgrade sequence could be:

```
3.5.1 -> 3.7.x -> 3.9.x -> 4.1.1
```

I agree with the comments by @Milo and @PieterGoosen; You shouldn't experiment with this on a production install, test this first on your dev install. Deactivate plugins before the upgrades and activate them afterwards, one at a time. Remember to activate the [debug log](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and scan through the `debug.log` for errors.

Remember to backup everything.

You can find the old releases [here](https://wordpress.org/download/release-archive/).

Comment: Thanks, for both the explanation and the link to older versions!

Comment: You're welcome and good luck with the upgrades ;-)