# Upgrading Across Multiple Versions

Tags: upgrade

Codex's recommendations on [Upgrading Across Multiple versions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Upgrading_WordPress_Extended#Upgrading_Across_Multiple_Versions) says:

> If you plan on upgrading across more than two major releases, please
>   consider upgrading incrementally to avoid potential conflicts and
>   minimize the risks of database damage. For example, if you plan on
>   upgrading from 2.5 to 4.2.2, upgrade to 2.7 first, followed by 2.9,
>   then 3.1, and so on. Essentially, it's okay to skip one release, but
>   never skip TWO when upgrading.

But given that minor releases within each major release fix bugs and security vulnerabilities, wouldn't it be better to upgrade to the last minor update within each major update to avoid those bugs and security vulnerabilities?

So using the above example, wouldn't it be the case to upgrade to 2.7.1 first, followed by 2.9.2 then 3.1.4 and so on?

P.S.: I'm aware of [similar](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/184574/why-did-my-manual-upgrade-fail) [questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/179565/site-needs-massive-upgrade-how-to-proceed) to this one, but none of them tackle the question of using an intermediate major version versus using the latest fixes in that major release.

Comment: The main issue with upgrade is with Database upgrade. The issue you are mentioning is not an issue at all. The wordpress core files are going to be same even if you jump from 2.7 to 4.2.2 or do it incrementally.

Comment: Couldn't something like the database update script be different between the first version of a major release and the subsequent ones?

Comment: Yes. It can be. But it's just a rule of thumb. It might not cause problem even if you skip all the version to final version. But I think it comes from experience of what works. But even if you follow this rule of thumb you should backup your database. Problem might happen during upgrading. Database is too valuable to take a chance against it.

Comment: All files and the database have been backed up as per the instructions contained in the document mentioned in the question.
As this is the first time I'm doing an upgrade across multiple versions, I took the extra step replicate the live site on a development machine and now I'm going to test step-by-step the whole upgrade procedure on dev before I try it on the live site.
The question remains: Is it better to use the last version of each major release for the intermediate upgrades?

Comment: I don't see any advantage whatsoever.